# "Unsupported get request" in Facebook Graph API when upgrading from 2.0 to 2.5

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upgrade my Graph API calls from 2.0 to 2.5 and I'm having some trouble with the "<album-id>/photos" endpoint with the following fields: comments, likes, place

When I make a request like (where 1763559189251 is the album.):

graph.facebook.com /v2.5/1763559189251/photos?limit=5000&fields=likes%2Ccomments%2Cplace&access_token=<TOKEN>

I receive the error bellow:

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request.",
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "BtbA83ph+vY"
}
}
```

Other fields like, height, width, id, created_time, tags, images, picture and name are working fine.

Why I receive this error only when I ask for this three fields (comments, likes and place)?

Does anyone can help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you need a user_posts permission in the token you are trying to get Timeline photos.

Comment: Now you don't need to ask for user_posts permission because the bug that is related here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/885008981626007/

It seems the "bug" was fixed.